# Bootstrap-table data-detail-view causing tbody to go to height: 0

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-table

I am trying to implement Bootstrap-Table's detailView into my project. Once I set my table to data-detail-view="true", the height of my  element of my table goes to 0. When I click on any of the columns that are sortable="true", it then expands the  displaying what is expected. It seems that when detailView is true, it is collapsing my entire table. I've gone through all of the JS and CSS to no avail. I have no custom JS that would be collapsing the table body either. Any suggestions would be helpful. If needed, I can post my code in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was an issue in some of my custom JS that is handling filters. When I introduced boostrap table, it pushes the column numbering +1 leading to incorrect filtering.